# python - count number of lines, words and char in one paragraph

Tags: python-3.x

I have below paragraph and I am trying to count number of line, number of words and number of char in python. New to Зython. I also tried but showing me number of lines :1

```
Gene expression in mammals is regulated by noncoding elements that can affect physiology and disease, yet the functions and target genes of most noncoding elements remain unknown. We present a high-throughput approach that uses clustered regularly interspaced short palindromic repeats (CRISPR) interference (CRISPRi) to discover regulatory elements and identify their target genes. We assess >1 megabase of sequence in the vicinity of two essential transcription factors, MYC and GATA1, and identify nine distal enhancers that control gene expression and cellular proliferation. Quantitative features of chromatin state and chromosome conformation distinguish the seven enhancers that regulate MYC from other elements that do not, suggesting a strategy for predicting enhancerâ€“promoter connectivity. This CRISPRi-based approach can be applied to dissect transcriptional networks and interpret the contributions of noncoding genetic variation to human disease.
```

Here is my code: I want to count number of lines in paragraph.

```
file_to_load = "raw_data/paragraph_1.txt"

with open(file_to_load, 'r') as reader:
    num_line = 0
    num_word = 0
    num_letter = 0        
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        wordsList = row.split()
        num_line += 1
        num_word += len(wordsList)
        num_letter += len(row)
        print(num_line)
        print(num_word)
        print(num_letter)
```

Comment: Are there any line breaks, newlines, carriage returns, etc. in the "paragraph"? The paragraph (as you've posted it in the question) looks like one long line, thus "showing number of lines: 1" looks like the correct output.

Comment: If you show your terminal output, it will make it easier for others to review your code. What do you see? What do you expect? Have you tried other test cases where you manually added line breaks?

Comment: This is paragraph which has 5 lines. I want to count number of lines in one para. My output should be 5 instead of 1.

Comment: I assume you mean ***sentences*** when you say ***lines***.  That distinction is causing confusion in the current answers.

Comment: Chuck out the following question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094351/code-for-counting-number-of-sentences-words-and-characters-in-an-input-file

Answer (score 0):

Your question states:

> I want to count number of lines in paragraph.

I ran your code directly without changes and it output:

```
1
130
968
```

The text you pasted is a single line of text, so the line count = 1 which is accurate. If you put a hard return `\n` in the text then it'll output 2.

Comment: that's the problem. I have Paragraph which has 5 lines. My output should 5 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph that you have provided consists of 1 line. The number of lines in a text document is equivalent to the number of "newline" characters ('\n'). So, in your case the entire contents of your paragraph are stored in the first line of your file.

Comment: thats a paragraph. My para has 5 lines. I want to count number of lines in one para. my output should be 5.

Comment: There is a simple check for that. Open your txt file in Notepad then go to Format and make sure Word Wrap is turned off. If the text becomes a single line that runs off the edge of your screen, then as far as Python is concerned your paragraph is one line. If it stays as 5 lines, then the problem is in something else.

Comment: Ok, to prove my point: I just saved your file as a txt, opened it, hit "enter" 5 times in random places, ran your script and got the correct output: 
5
130
969

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
NumberOfLines=len(re.split('\n',yourFile))
NumberOfWords=len(re.split(' ',yourFile))
NumberOfChars=len(yourFile)
```